# Powershell Run as Administrator errors out

Tags: powershell, administrator, runas

Trying to run this script on a non bound computer but seems to crash every time. Works fine on my computer which makes me think maybe its permission based? The non bound computer is a local admin account running the script, it opens a 2nd Powershell module then quits everything with no error message. I can launch powershell as admin then run the script but that is not the goal im trying to achieve.

```
Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
    $myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
    $myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);

    # Get the security principal for the administrator role
    $adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

    # Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
    if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
        # We are running as an administrator, so change the title and background colour to indicate this
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)";
        $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
        Clear-Host;
    }
    else {
        # We are not running as an administrator, so relaunch as administrator

        # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
        $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

        # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter with added scope and support for scripts with spaces in it's path
        $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"

        # Indicate that the process should be elevated
        $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

        # Start the new process
        [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

        # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
        Exit;
    }

    # Run your code that needs to be elevated here...



    Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue...";
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
```

Update: I managed to record a video and capture the error thats displayed:

```
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element product an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a commandInfo object.
At line:1 char:3 
+& ''
+  ~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation (:String)[], RuntimeException
+ FullyQulifiedErrorId : BadExpression
```

Comment: As an aside: `;` is only ever needed in PowerShell if you want to place _multiple_ commands on a _single_ line.

Comment: If I run this script in command prompt, it does the same crash, no error code. However when i run cmd as administrator, it get it to work